# Keyboard library python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, keyboard, python-keyboard

I am trying to do a python script and while the script is running in the background I want it to listen at some buttons, the problem is that I can't even this simple program to get to work, I get segmentation fault 11. When I run it I use `sudo python3 prog.py`.

```
import keyboard
keyboard.wait('esc')
print("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. You don't compile a Python program
2. The problem is that you don't have permission to access that memory, hence the segfault. The fix depends on your system, on my Mac I just changed the permissions of the terminal (so that it could control my computer).
3. Also, I just want to mention that a process in the background does not take in data from STDIN, so you may have a problem there depending on what you mean.

Comment: Thx! It solved the problem. Mb I meant run the script!